# How can I record and replay axis input accurately for testing?

Tags: unity, c#, testing

I want to do integration testing for an old C#/Unity project. The project uses its own input system, so I can't use `inputEventTrace` or any other convenient Unity class. So I subscribed a new game object to the custom input system so that it records any input detected in each frame.

But when I replay, because of the difference in frame times, the replays are not quite equal to the original playthrough (especially because of the axis input). My understanding is that input in Unity is not event-based, so I can't think of any way to perfectly mimic the input given different frame times. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7728186-creating-a-replay-system-in-unity

Comment: nice link Almo! In company where I was working , we were brainstorming best plan for replay (just one part of game needed to be replayed if user wish to see how he won/lost,- part where fighter units come and destroy buildings and enemies - sort of mini starcraft style). At the end we thought best for us to record most important things - like kills, deaths, start of path, etc and to 'fake' others - like we knew path units will take will differ slightly at each replay but we thought it will be good enough for our purposes...

Comment: Cool link, but i did say it was for testing. You cant test with a state replay system

Comment: Can you read the input during `FixedUpdate()` instead of during `Update()`?

Comment: Since you're asking from a testing perspective, you could use something like - Unium - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/unium-automated-test-tools-95998 with this included, its just a short step to integrate selenium (https://www.selenium.dev).